# A silly doubt on the impossibility of surjection $A\to P(A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a minor detail in this proof:

> **2.21. Theorem (Cantor).**
>   For every set $A$,
>   $$
>   A <_c \mathcal{P}(A),
> $$
>   i.e., $A \leq_c \mathcal{P}(A)$ but $A \neq_c \mathcal{P}(A)$;
>   in fact there is no surjection $\pi \colon A \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$.
>
> *Proof.*
>   That  $A \leq_c \mathcal{P}(A)$ follows from the fact that the function
>   $$
>   (x \mapsto \{x\})
> $$
>   which associates with each member $x$ of $A$ its **singleton** $\{x\}$ is an injection.
>   (Careful here: the singleton $\{x\}$ is a set with just the one member $x$ and it is not the same object as $x$, which is probably not a set to begin with!)
>
> To complete the proof, we assume (towards a contradiction) that there exists a surjection
>   $$
>   \pi \colon A \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{P}(A),
> $$
>   and we define the set
>   $$
>   B = \{ x \in A \mid x \notin \pi(x) \},
> $$
>   so that for every $x \in A$,
>   $$
>   x \in B \iff x \notin \pi(x).
> $$
>   Now $B$ is a subset of $A$ and $\pi$ is a surjection, so there must exist some $b \in A$ such that $B = \pi(b)$;
>   and setting $x = b$ and $\pi(b) = B$, we get
>   $$
>   b \in B \iff b \notin B
> $$

I am confused with the choice of $B$ here. I understand that we *could* make a surjection this way, after all we are mapping each $a\in A$ to an element of $P(A)$ that does not contain $a$, that is: Something like:

$$1\to\{2,3\}\\ 2\to \{1,3\}$$

And this yields that problematic conclusion. I understood the proof, but I don't understand why this choice of $B$ proves that there is no surjection. That is: Why couldn't we construct $B$ in another form such that the surjection is achievable? Does the sole existence of this construction of $B$ denies the surjection? Why?

Comment: The issue is not "how to build the surjection" (there is none !); the issue is : "assume that there is a surjection $\pi$". By def of [surjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Definition) : for any $y \in \mathcal P(A)$, there is an $x \in A$ such that : $\pi(x)=y$.

Comment: Now we define $B$ in that way; it is a "reasonable" subset of $A$ and thus $B \in \mathcal P(A)$. By the def of $\pi$ (we have assumed that $\pi$ exists), there is $b \in A$ such that $\pi(b)=B$. Then we use (2-1) and it's done.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes. Thanks. I messed up the words a little bit.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $B$ is built on two predicates $ x \in A, x \notin \pi(x)$. My question is more akin to the following: Suppose there is a $B'$ in $n$ reasonable predicates: $B'=\{P_1,P_2,P_3,\dots \}$. So if at least one combination of these predicates yields a problem, then the surjection does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to formulate the proof is not by contradiction, but rather by contrapositive: let $\pi\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$ be *any* function, we define a set $B_\pi\in\mathcal P(A)$ such that $\pi(a)\neq B_\pi$ for all $a\in A$. In other words, we show that $\pi$ is not surjective.

Now, the important thing to note is that the definition of $B$ *depends* on $\pi$, and it works for *any* $\pi$. It's not just for surjective functions; and different $\pi$ will produce different $B$'s.

---

Let's look at two examples:

### Example I:

> $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $\pi(a)=\{a\}$.

Then we define $B$ to be $\{a\in A\mid a\notin\pi(a)\}$, which in turn translates with this specific $\pi$ to be $B=\{a\in A\mid a\notin\{a\}\}$. Of course, this $B$ has to be empty. But lo and behold, $\pi(0),\pi(1)$ and $\pi(2)$ are all non-empty. So $B$ is not in the range of $\pi$.

### Example II:

> $A=\Bbb N$ and $\pi(n)=\{k\mid\ n^2\mid k\}$, namely $\pi(n)$ is the set of all those $k$ such that $n^2$ divides $k$ (in this context, every number—including $0$—divides itself).

What does the definition of $B$ gives us now? It's the set $\{n\mid\  n^2\nmid n\}$, which is exactly $\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$. But now we ask if there is a number $n$ such that $n^2$ divides *all* the natural numbers *except* $0$ and $1$? Since every number divides $0$, the answer is easily negative; but also by arguing through prime numbers if you prefer: $n^2\nmid 2$ for *any* natural number except $1$, but since $1^2\mid 1$, and $1\notin B$, it is impossible that $B=\pi(1)$, so $B$ is not $\pi(n)$ for any $n$.

---

### TL;DR

So to recap, $B$ is defined *from* $\pi$ to conclude that $B$ is not in the image of $\pi$. This definition depends on $\pi$, but it works for *every* $\pi\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: I am a little bit confused at the logical structure of the proof: We suppose that there is a surjection, then every $x\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ must be mapped to an element of $A$ and then, the set $B$ which is constructed with two predicates $x \in A, x \notin \pi(x)$. So, the proof seems to rely on the construction of a set $\{P_1 :P_2 : \dots P_n \}\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ with an arbitrary number of *reasonable* predicates, such that if at least one of the combinations of predicates from all the combinations of predicates can't be mapped, then the answer is negative. Is that it?

Comment: What? No. The proof starts with *one* function, and constructs *one* set. There is no "set of predicates" or combinations. We literally define a set which is not in the range of the given function.

Comment: No, I meant: There is a set constructed with predicates.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "predicates".

Comment: For example, these: $x \in A, x \notin \pi(x)$.

Comment: Okay. Then yes. We construct a set with these two predicates and then we can ensure it is not in the image of $\pi$.

Comment: No, I'm asking the following we could build various $B$'s. For example: $B=\{x \in A\}, B'=\{ x \notin \pi(x) \}, B''=\{x \in A : x \notin \pi(x) \},\dots$. From all the $B$'s that we could be constructed, if one of them presents a problem, then the surjection can't be made?

Comment: I don't follow your question. You have a function from $A$ to $\mathcal P(A)$. Using this function, we have constructed a set $B$ which is not in the range of the function. Therefore the function is not surjective. There will be many sets not in the range of the functions, and many of them can might be definable as predicates (in a nontrivial way, that is). Review the definition of "surjective function" to recall that one counterexample is enough to refute this property.

Answer (score 3):

The point is that if $\pi$ is surjective, then **every** subset of $A$ is in its range; in particular, the $B$ from the proof.

Comment: This is one of the things I thought about: Perhaps its just one example that fails the *for all constructions of $B$, there is this one which fails.*

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What the proof does is: given $\pi:A\to\mathcal P(A)$, there exists $B\subset A$ such that $B$ is not in the range of $\pi$. So $\pi$ is not surjective.

Comment: @oppa ,surjection asks for all subset of $A$ to follow the condition so even if one fails to fulfill the condition, surjection is disproved.

Answer (score 2):

The construction of $B$ occurs after the construction of the surjection. That is, as long as there is a function from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$, we can define such a set $B$. You can't "construct $B$ in another way" because regardless of what other set you construct, $B$ will still exist if you have a function, and hence $B$ gives us the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You could think about Cantor's theorem as a "corollary" to what is truly proven.

**Proposition.**
For each set $ X $ and for each $ f:X\to \mathscr{P}\left(X\right) $, there exists $ Y\in\mathscr{P}\left(X\right) $ such that $ Y\notin \operatorname{ran}\left(f\right) $.

*Proof.*
Let $ X $ be an arbitrary set.
Let $ f:X\to\mathscr{P}\left(X\right) $ be arbitrary.
Define $ Y:=\left\{z\in X:z\notin f\left(z\right)\right\} $.
By contradiction, suppose $ Y\in\operatorname{ran}\left(f\right) $.
Therefore there exists $ x\in X $ such that $ f\left(x\right)=Y $.

(I) Assume $ x\in Y $.
Therefore $ x\in X $ and $ x\notin f\left(x\right) $.
Because $ f\left(x\right)=Y $, $ x\notin Y $---a contradiction.

(II) Assume $ x\notin Y $.
Therefore $ x\notin X $ or $ x\in f\left(x\right) $.
Because $ x\in X $, $ x\in f\left(x\right) $.
Because $ f\left(x\right)=Y $, $ x\in Y $---a contradiction.

As a result, $ Y\notin\operatorname{ran}\left(f\right) $.

---

EDIT: To elaborate further:

Recall

- A function $f:A\to B$ is surjective if for each $b\in B$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.
- The range of a function $f:A\to B$ is $\mathrm{ran}(f):=\{b\in B:(\exists a)[a\in A\,\wedge\, f(a)=b]\}$.

**Corollary.** For each set $X$, there does not exist a surjection $f:X\twoheadrightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$.

*Proof.*
Let $X$ be an arbitrary set.
By contradiction, suppose there exists a surjection $f:X\twoheadrightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$.
Because $f$ is a function from $X$ to $\mathscr{P}(X)$, there exists $Y\in\mathscr{P}(X)$ such that $Y\notin \mathrm{ran}(f)$.
Because $f$ is surjective and $Y\in \mathscr{P}(X)$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=Y$.
Therefore $Y\in\mathrm{ran}(f)$---a contradiction.
As a result, there does not exist a surjection $f:X\twoheadrightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$.